# How to fill out nulls according to another dataframe pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I currently started using pyspark. I have a two columns dataframe with one column containing some nulls, e.g.

```
df1
A             B
1a3b          7
0d4s          12
6w2r          null
6w2r          null
1p4e          null
```

and another dataframe has the correct mapping, i.e.

```
df2
A             B
1a3b          7
0d4s          12
6w2r          0
1p4e          3
```

so I want to fill out the nulls in `df1` using `df2` s.t. the result is:

```
A             B
1a3b          7
0d4s          12
6w2r          0
6w2r          0
1p4e          3
```

in pandas, I would first create a lookup dictionary from `df2` then use apply on the `df1` to populate the nulls. But I'm not really sure what functions to use in pyspark, most of replacing nulls I saw is based on simple conditions, for example, filling all the nulls to be a single constant value for certain column.

What I have tried is:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import when, col

df1.withColumn('B', when(df.B.isNull(), df2.where(df2.B== df1.B).select('A')))
```

although I was getting `AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute '_get_object_id'`. The logic is to first filter out the nulls then replace it with the column B's value from df2, but I think `df.B.isNull()` evaluates the whole column instead of single value, which is probably not the right way to do it, any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*left join* on *common column A* and *selecting appropriate columns* should get you your desired output

```
df1.join(df2, df1.A == df2.A, 'left').select(df1.A, df2.B).show(truncate=False)
```

which should give you

```
+----+---+
|A   |B  |
+----+---+
|6w2r|0  |
|6w2r|0  |
|1a3b|7  |
|1p4e|3  |
|0d4s|12 |
+----+---+
```

Comment: It works! But I still wonder how you can populate the nulls directly by checking conditions, and what are the advantages of using one over another method? If most of the values in `B` of `df1` are not nulls, I guess `join` is a overkill?

Comment: You can separate df1 into two dataframes. one with nulls and one with not nulls. join the nulls as done in the answer and then finally union them both. that should be efficient and fast